# How to get Hudson to show details of git repository changes?

Tags: git, hudson

We are switching from ClearCase to do Hudson-based builds from Git repositories. With ClearCase, we could see the differences between each commit by clicking on 'changes', like this:

```
1. username on 15/03/2012 22:55:02
Important change message
The file was modified   /full/path/to/pom.xml@/main/10 - create version
```

But now, with Git, the changes view only shows this:

```
Commit aebb135ce48bd5b47b825a16f65da52ddc4d50c4 by firstname lastname

Important change message

The file was modified   pom.xml
```

There are lot of pom.xml's in our repo, and checking using commit hash every time is not very convenient. Is there a way to get Hudson to show the actual file with full path and date/time?

Comment: That's a function of the specific VCS's plugin. If you have a gitweb instance somewhere, you might consider adding the URL for it to your job config; that'll add a link to the change's gitweb page. (I forget whether a separate plugin is required for gitweb integration or if the Git vcs support includes that field.)

Comment: We have our own hosting of Git repositories, within our intra. Does that mean that this cannot be done without us writing a plugin for it?

Comment: Based on [the hudson book](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.html#section-scm-git-project), gitweb, redmineweb and githubweb are supported by default. Would this mean that for an intra repo one has to implement such interface?

Comment: gitweb is a package that you can run locally.

Comment: if you could add that as an answer so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [gitweb](http://progit.org/book/ch4-6.html) configured, you can add the URL for it to Hudson's job config and it will provide links for changes there. (Hudson's git support has support for gitweb by default.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the maybe you can write your commit info more clearly.

Comment: You mean to manually add dates, times and the full path on every commit message? Err... doesn't sound too tempting. :)

of course, we could implement a commit hook to do that, but it still doesn't sound like the optimal way.

Comment: hah :)  you are right, most of people do not like this solution.